# Convert date from long time postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

How do I select the date as a readable string from epoch time in milliseconds?

Some like: `SELECT *, to_date(time_in_milli_sec) FROM mytable`

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Per [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-formatting.html):

```
SELECT *, to_timestamp(time_in_milli_sec / 1000) FROM mytable
```

Comment: It should be divided by a float 1000.0, not 1000, otherwise milliseconds will be dropped.

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT timestamp 'epoch' + time_in_millisec * interval '1 ms'
FROM   mytable;
```

See the [manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html)

Answer (score 3):

For milliseconds

```
SELECT timestamp 'epoch' + proyecto.fecha_inicio * interval '1 ms'
from proyecto.proyecto
where proyecto.fecha_inicio is not null
```

For seconds

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 982384720 * INTERVAL '1 second';
```

In the manual : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html.

Line:  .. "Here is how you can convert an epoch value back to a time stamp"..

Answer (score 1):

Original question was related to Date data type, but all the answers so far relate to Timestamp data type.

One way to convert milliseconds to Date would be:

```
SELECT DATE(any_time_field_containing_milliseconds/ 1000) FROM mytable;
```

This seems to use the timezone defined for database